# Can I use single SetSubclassWindow procedure to subclass multiple edit controls, and if I can, how to do it?

Tags: c++, winapi

Can I use single SetSubclassWindow procedure to subclass multiple edit controls, and if I can, how to do it?

I want to subclass multiple edit controls with the same subclass procedure.

So far, I did it like this:

```
SetWindowSubclass( GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT1 ), SomeSubclassProcedure, 0, 0);

SetWindowSubclass( GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT2 ), SomeSubclassProcedure, 0, 0);
```

Everything works, but I just want to check with more experienced developers, so I can be sure, since I am a beginner.

Also, I would like to know if I should use RemoveWindowSubclass when I destroy dialog box that contains edit controls.

I haven't used it in my code, since I pass no data as 4th parameter to the SetWindowSubclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing wrong with this in itself.

The only thing to be careful of is if you use any global/shared data that might need to be maintained per-control. You can handle this by providing a different value for `dwRefData` when you sub-class the control - e.g. you could allocate a different data structure for each control, but still use the same subclass procedure.

You definitely **do** need to call `RemoveWindowSubclass` for each control you have sub-classed - either when your dialog is destroyed, or in the sub-class itself when the control is destroyed:

```
// subclass procedure
case WM_NCDESTROY:
    RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, SubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
```

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for! You have explained it just the way I needed. Thank you, +1 from me :))